# Problem on conditions on the divisors of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've recently started exploring elementary number theory, and came across the book Number Theory for Beginners by André Weil, which is where I found this problem.

The problem is:

> Prove that any integer $x>1$ has either a divisor $>1$ and $ \leq
>  \sqrt{x}$ or no divisor between $1$ and $x$.

I'm not sure how to go about proving this. I thought I would try a proof by contradiction, but then I'm a little confused about the what the negation of the problem would be.

Let (1) denote the problem. Suppose that (1) is false, then there exists $a \in\mathbb{Z^+}$ that has either a divisor, $d$, that satisfies $d>\sqrt{x}$ or ... (here is where I am not sure)

Comment: I meant to only write $ \leq $. I will edit the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $ab=x$, and for simplicity assume $a\leq b$. Could it be true that $a>\sqrt x$?

Answer (score 0):

The negation is that there exists an $a$ such that both the possibilities are false. The second statement being false means that there is a divisor strictly between $1$ and $x$ and the first statement being false means that there is no divisor between $1$ and $\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then, if $x$ is prime, then it has divisors $1$ and $x$, so it has no divisor between $1$ and $x$.

If $x$ is not prime we can write it in the form $x=ab$ where $a \neq 1,p$ and $b \neq 1,p$, now suppose that both $a$ and $b$ are $> \sqrt x$. Then we would have $x=ab> \sqrt x \cdot \sqrt x =x$ , which is impossible, so either $a$ or $b$ are $\leq \sqrt x$, or both if $a=b= \sqrt x$, when $x$ is square.